Finding Determinant of an 100x100 matrix
I had a dream where I had to solve the determinant of an 100x100 matrix by hand. Is there a better way of doing this than using Laplace expansion? Thank you

Gauss elimination.

I don't think such dreams are sane. :)

If you need to compute a $100\times100$ determinant in reality, use the fact that $\det$ is a skew symmetric, multilinear function.

@Nuaptan ... and presumably some other idea that is actually good?
